# Positioning Elements in Tableless Layout

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do a [tableless
layout](http://www.w3.org/2002/03/csslayout-howto), and I have the following
HTML snippet:

```
<div class="slider-inner">
    <div class="slider-pane">
        <div class="container">
            <p>...</p>
            <div class="did-you-knoow">
                <div class="facts">
                </div>
                <div class="marquee-container">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which is styled w/ this CSS:

```
div.slider-pane {
    width: 1024px;
}

div.container {
    display: block;
}

div.facts {
    margin-right: 60%;
}

div.marquee-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 60%;
}
```

I want the `div.facts` to occupy the left-40% , and the `div.marquee-container`
to occupy the right-60% of the `div.did-you-know` (their immediate parent).  I
expect the `div.marquee-container` to be positioned relative to its parent, and
its width to be 60% of its parent, but its positioning and width are relative
to `div.slider-inner`, which is 2 levels above its parent.

**How do I set the position and width of `div.marquee-container` relative to
its parent, and not the div three levels above it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `position:relative` to `div.container`

Comment: Thanks, this worked after I added this to the direct parent as well (I explained in my answer below).

Answer (score 0):

@locrizak's answer is correct, I needed to add 'position:relative' to the `div.container`, but I needed to add it to the `div.did-you-know` as well.  In other words, I needed to set all of the containing div's to `position:relative` in order for the elements in question to be positioned relative to the immediate parent.

I found this was also answered in [the MDN page for css position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position) under the 'absolute' definition:

> [The browser will] position [the element] at a specified position relative to its *closest positioned ancestor* or to the containing block

However [the W3C reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#choose-position) was not as helpful.